# "Contributions by" or "from"?

Tags: prepositions

> The yearbook is made with love by Lisa, with contributions **by** Mary and Sal.

or

> The yearbook is made with love by Lisa, with contributions **from** Mary and Sal.

Comment: Technically, both the prepositions are fine. In the context, though, *from* works much better.

Comment: The phrase "contributions **[from/by]** Mary and Sal" can be understood to mean "contributions **received from** Mary and Sal" or to mean "contributions **written by** Mary and Sal." As a result, both "from" and "by" are defensible.